# How to create a one-time welcome screen using Android preferences?

Tags: android, version, sharedpreferences

I'd like to create a screen that only shows once after the application starts. Afterward, then it will only show the main screen. The way I implemented this was just to check the preferences and set the current layout based on a flag. Are there any draw backs to implementing it this way? Is there a better way?

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Here is the main layout
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      

        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        // second argument is the default to use if the preference can't be found
        Boolean welcomeScreenShown = mPrefs.getBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, false);

        if (!welcomeScreenShown) {
            //Here I set the one-time layout
            setContentView(R.layout.popup_message);             
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, true);
            editor.commit(); // Very important to save the preference
        }
    }
```

Comment: You solution is reasonable. Only thing you might want to change is to also store the version of your app. When user upgrades from older version, you might want to show the welcome screen again. However, the preferences are not wiped during the update, thus your current solution does not handle that case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with **Application version code**. Below is an example code that I have used;

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("version", 0);
    int savedVersionCode = sharedPreferences.getInt("VersionCode", 0);

    int appVershionCode = 0;

    try {
        appVershionCode = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;

    } catch (NameNotFoundException nnfe) {
        Log.w(TAG, "$ Exception caz of appVershionCode : " + nnfe);
    }   

    if(savedVersionCode == appVershionCode){
        Log.d(TAG, "$$ savedVersionCode == appVershionCode");
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "$$ savedVersionCode != appVershionCode");

        SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        sharedPreferencesEditor.putInt("VersionCode", appVershionCode);
        sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();

        Builder alertDialogBuilder = new Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Version");
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("This is one time show dialog box ");

        alertDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton("Close", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Log.d(TAG, "$$ onClick");

            }
        });

        alertDialogBuilder.show();
    }
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for today.

Comment: The AlertDialogBuilder is a nice touch, but you'll need to specify the class AlertDialog.Builder when you initialize it. Furthermore, you'll need to set alertDialogBuilder.show();

Comment: @AnujAroshA Does this show the one time alert dialog if the user install the 2nd version instead of updating from the 1st version???

Comment: @AnujAroshA I think when an existing user updates the application then he will see the one time alert again as per your code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of shared preference you can use below code also i have used this many times it will work perfectly it shows only one time when application start first time

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
protected boolean _isActive = true;
protected int _splashTime = 3000; //SplashActivity will be visible for 2s
final String TAG = "SplashActivity";


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);



    //a separate thread to manage splash screen
    final Thread splashThread = new Thread() {

        public void run() {

            try {
                int wait = 0;

                while (_isActive && (_splashTime > wait)) { //will show only on the first time
                    sleep(100);

                    if (_isActive) {
                        wait += 100;
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());

            } finally {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivityAbs.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    splashThread.start();
}

//if a user clicks on a back btnOrder, do not show splash screen

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        _isActive = false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any indication that this piece of code will start only for the first time of the app's usage.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Alpaslan sorry for that